# Does an iOS App Clip need the Push Notification capability if its App already has it?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, remote-notifications, apple-appclips

I have an existing ios Swift App that is configured with the Push Notification capability. It can receive push notifications ok.

As part of adding an App Clip to the App, do I need to also add the Push Notification capability to the App Clip?

If that is the case, do I also need to create/register an additional set of Push Notifications SSL certificates with Apple to be able to send remote messages to the app/appclip or can I use the existing SSL certificate that I registered for the App?

Comment: App clips can't show notification, so no need to configure APNs settings for these.